# Reference for log-loss (cross-entropy)?

Tags: references, cross-entropy, scoring-rules, log-loss

I'm trying to track down the original reference for the [logarithmic loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) (logarithmic scoring rule, cross-entropy), usually defined as:

$$L_{log}=y_{true} \log(p) + (1-y_{true}) \log(1-p)$$

For the Brier score for example there is the [Brier (1950)](https://doi.org/10.1175%2F1520-0493%281950%29078%3C0001%3Avofeit%3E2.0.co%3B2) article. Is there such a reference for the log-loss?

Comment: shouldn't cross-entropy have two different distributions, not the same ($p$)?

Comment: The metric is defined in full in the link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#log-loss

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31985/definition-and-origin-of-cross-entropy

Comment: @Sycorax: Does it not qualify as a plain duplicate? I feel like I might be missing the difference if there is any.

Comment: @user541686 My answer writes about a slim distinction that I perceive between the two. I can see a case made for either closing as a duplicate or letting this more specific variation on the theme stand on its own.

Comment: @Sycorax: Oh I see, thanks! Up to you I guess, I'm not sure.

Comment: @user541686 The other aspect is that since I have an answer here, it might appear self-interested in some sense to close this thread (other SO communities have had disputes and hurt feelings about this exact scenario, and I wish to avoid that).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The earliest I have been able to find is

> Good, I. J. “Rational Decisions.” Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological), vol. 14, no. 1, 1952, pp. 107–114. JSTOR, [www.jstor.org/stable/2984087](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2984087)

Look at section 8, "Fair Fees":

> By itself $\log p_1$ (or $\log(1 - p_1)$) is a measure of the merit of a probability estimate

I found this reference in [Gneiting & Raftery (2007, *JASA*)](http://www.tandfonline.com/action/showCitFormats?doi=10.1198/016214506000001437), who write that "This scoring rule dates back at least to Good (1952)", suggesting that they already did a similar search for original sources.

Comment: Selecting this answer as it adheres more closely to the modern definition of log-loss. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

If we view minimizing cross entropy as equivalent to maximizing the log-likelihood of the same model, then I believe we can go as far back as RA Fisher. This places the date between 1912 and 1922, depending on how well-developed you wish the theory to be; see discussion in
John Aldrich "R. A. Fisher and the Making of Maximum
Likelihood 1912 – 1922" *Statistical Science*. 1997, Vol. 12, No. 3, 162-176

We also have some related threads:

- [How to construct a cross-entropy loss for general regression targets?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378274/how-to-construct-a-cross-entropy-loss-for-general-regression-targets)
- [Definition and origin of “cross entropy”](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31985/definition-and-origin-of-cross-entropy)

which use the term "cross entropy" in the broad sense of a *family of probabilistic losses*, instead of the sense used in this post, as *jargon* for a specific loss for a model of binary data.